# laravel middleware applying to specific route

Tags: controller, laravel-5, routes, middleware

I am using larave 5.2

I need to apply middleware route

Controller

```
 public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth',['only'=>'profile.create']);

}
```

Route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {


Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');




Route::resource('profile','ProfiledetailsController');


});
```

When I use below code it works, but middleware applied to all the method of the controller

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth');

}
```

route:list

[image: route:list]
<sub>(source: [huda-enterprises.com](http://huda-enterprises.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Screen-Shot-2016-02-04-at-12.09.42.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
public function __construct() {    
  $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => 'create'])
}
```

Comment: HI @Timo , I have tried as you mentioned above. It worked. Can you explain as it doesn't make any sense to me.    As in future I have more controllers with create route. This might conflict and applied to all the controller with 'create'

Comment: Your route /profile uses ProfiledetailsController class and this constructor inside is for the ProfileDetailsController class. So if you use middleware like this --- $this->middleware('auth'); --- it assigns the middleware to whole class. So the route /profile uses this middleware, which means the class ProfileDetailsController and all of its methods use this middleware. Since the constructor builds ProfiledetailsController class, you do not have to specify the route itself. You need to specify the method within this class only. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: PS: You don't have to worry about any conflicts, since this middleware applies only to ProfiledetailsController class Create method